# Using socket io to add a marker to a google map when a new user logs in

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, sockets, socket.io

I have a google map that is geolocating the user and placing a marker on the map.
I am wanting A new marker to be added when a new user loads the map.
To do this I am using socket io.

However the desired result is not happening!
Users and not seeing each other and markers seem to be continuing to generate the longer the browser stays open.

**REPO AT https://github.com/Stacca/geo-socket**

Any suggestion appreciated thank you!.

**My Node Server looks like this..**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var path = require("path")
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app/index.html'));
});


var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');

socket.on('marker', function(data) {

console.log('marker latitude: ' + data.lat + ', marker longitude:' +      
data.lng);
socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data);
});

});
http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('five minute catch up is on port 3000');
});

module.exports = server;
```

**My JS file**

```
"use strict";
var map;
var markers = []

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 16
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center); 
});


if(navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: 'You are here'
  });

  map.setCenter(pos);
  }, function() {
  handleNoGeolocation(true);
  });
} else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
}
function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
if (errorFlag) {
var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
} else {
var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
}

var options = {
map: map,
position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
content: content
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


// listen for Marker event
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'load', function(event) {

var marker = addMarker(event.latLng);


socket.emit('marker', {
    'lat': marker.position.k,
    'lng': marker.position.D
});
});

// Add a marker to the map 
function addMarker(location) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
});

markers.push(marker);

console.log(location);
console.log("marker: " + marker.position.k + " " + marker.position.D);

return marker;
}

//Listens for other users markers
socket.on('show-marker', addMarker);
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet"   
href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/main.css">
<!--    Internal map style (cant remove)-->
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map-canvas { height: 90%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
<!--   Public API  -->
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
```

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>  
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js">  
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js">
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js">
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js">
</script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>


    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="app/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="app/scripts/map.js"></script>
    <script src="app/scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- socket scripts -->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script> var socket = io();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the html sample in order to test the behavior?

The code seems to be right, wich is the specific problem that you have?   Also you need to consider following cases:

1) Store a list of actual markers, so when a user enter to the site for first time it will add all the markers that are active.
2) Remove a marker when a user get disconected from the socket.

Comment: yes, thank you. Attaching HTML now. The problem is a new user (i.e new browser on localhost 3000) does not generate a new marker..

Comment: Is taking more than expected to get it working properly (can run the app but seems like the addMarker is never called (maybe map event never fire), so i was starting to call socket.emit when the 'info' window is showing, the server get the socket message but seems that the client is not recieving any when emmit 'show-marker'.

I will take a deeply look at the afternoon-night. sry.

Comment: wow thanks for you knowledge.. I will continue too. Your time is appreciated..

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are the points successfully sent to the server? then back down again???

Comment: I have an error of  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined.. It logs a user connection but does not make a log of location or position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem runs deeper than the code.

Correct me if I am wrong but I would need a session so the browser knows there are two users?

Or some way of giving the users a unique identifier.

have added a listen to HTMl

```
    socket.on('show-marker', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,
                                   data.lng);
    addMarker(loc, data.socketId);
```

and this has helped

Answer (score 0):

In your show-marker event, you are not calling the function, or passing in the data. Your code line on the client:

```
socket.on('show-marker', addMarker);
```

Should be:

```
socket.on('show-marker', addMarker(location));
```

Without the parentheses you aren't calling the function, you are simply referencing the function's location in memory, this is why addMarker never fired. Without the parameter the addMarker function receives a null, and it won't be able to add the marker.

Comment: Yes that is one of the major problems.. But also the add event listener that send the marker message to the server also is never called. So server does not receive a message an then cant execute the callback that emmits show marker

Comment: Do you mean in the server? 
I thought this would display the new marker.
    socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data);

Comment: I have updated in server markers.push(socket.id) no luck